# Como asociar y limitar objetos a usuarios en campo ManyToMany Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, djangorestframework, django-views

soy bastante nuevo en Django, y estoy haciendo una Api con django rest.

Tengo 2 modelos, uno es purchase_request y otro es purchase_approval, purchase_request genera ordenes y en este se encuentra un campo llamado grupo_aprobador de muchos a muchos con los usuarios que pueden aprobar la orden, ahora lo que me pidieron es filtrar en purchase_approval, para que en cuando un usuario inicie sesion solo le aparezcan las ordenes que les hayan sido asociadas a él a través del campo grupo_aprobador.

Por ejemplo en vez de al seleccionar en que purchase_request va a aprobar y le aparezcan todas las ordenes, en este caso que solo le aparezcan las asociadas a el solamente.

Aca es como esta actualmente, me retorna todas las ordenes, no solo las asociadas a el
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**models.py**

```
class PurchaseRequest(models.Model):
    grupo_aprobador = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name = "Grupo Aprobador", related_name = "grupo_aprobador")
    ### Otros campos ###

class PurchaseApproval(models.Model):
    usuario_aprobador = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    purchase_request = models.ForeignKey(PurchaseRequest, on_delete=models.RESTRICT, verbose_name = "Purchase Request", related_name="purchase_request")
    # Otros campos ###
```

**Views.py**

```
class PurchaseApprovalViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [DjangoModelPermissions]
    serializer_class = PurchaseApprovalSerializer

    def get_queryset(self,pk=None):
        if pk is None:
            user = self.request.user
            return self.get_serializer().Meta.model.objects.filter(purchase_request__grupo_aprobador=user.id)
        return self.get_serializer().Meta.model.objects.filter(id=pk).first()
```

Intente usando filter(purchase_request__grupo_aprobador=user.id) pero devuelve una lista vacía.

### **Actualizacion:**

En este caso no se debe cambiar el queryset con filter como intentaba sino ¿Se debe cambiar la clave primaria del modelo purchase_request quizas de algun modo? Para poder limitar las claves foraneas a las que puede tomar el usuario purchase_approval

Ej: Si en purchase_request se agrego a user@user.com entonces ese usuario solo puede aprobar ese purchase_request y no otro.

Cualquier sugerencia, si se necesita más información o cambiar algo referente a la pregunta lo hare sin problemas.

Comment: Tienes `DjangoModelPermissions`. Para fines de debugueo cambialo por `AllowAny`. Otra cosa, por que no simplemente llamas `PurchaseApproval.objects.filter(id=pk).first()` ?

Comment: Si DjangoModelPermissions verifica si el usuario actual tiene permiso de GET, POST, PUT y DELETE, y tengo 2 return ya que el primero es para GET de lista y el segundo el que contiene una PK es para RETRIEVE, PUT y DELETE

Comment: Es pregunta? no pusiste `AllowAny`?

Comment: No, no puse AllowAny para debug, ya que necesito saber que usuario esta conectado, si dejo AllowAny y tengo en la vista request.user me dara un error, y en este caso el usuario aprobador de alguna manera debe saber a que purchase_request esta asociado para que al seleccionarlo (Como se muestra en la primera foto) solo le indique a los que el esta asociado y no todas las claves foraneas. Tendria que de alguna manera limitar las claves foraneas asociadas a ese usuario aprobador.

Comment: Por si no lo sabias `AllowAny` no modifica el usuario. Como su nombre lo indica es de permisos. Tambie dije que era para fines de debugueo.

Comment: Ok , lo cambie a AllowAny, funciona todo correcto, el listar sólo muestra los purchase_request que haya hecho el usuario actual y en purchase_approval tambien, hasta ahi todo bien, pero sigue estando mi pregunta de cómo limitarlo, Por ejemplo si el usuario A fue asignado al purchase_request N°1, solo al usuario A le debe aparecer el purchase_request 1 desde el purchase_approval para que la pueda aprobar, si un Usuario B ingresa a purchase_approval, este no debe poder ver o modificar el purchase_request 1. Igualmente gracias por darte el tiempo de tratar de ayudarme.

Answer (score 0):

El error está en la linea

```
...objects.filter(purchase_request__grupo_aprobador=user.id)
```

`grupo_aprobador` es una lista de usuarios. Ademas de que lo comparas con el `id`. Osea un `int`.

Cambialo por:

```
objects.filter(purchase_request__grupo_aprobador__user__id=user.id)
```